# cdf for first success

Tags: probability

I had two ways of computing the CDF for a first success distribution.

$ X \sim FS(p)$

$p_X(x) = P(X = x) = (1 - p)^{x-1}p = q^{x-1}p$

**Method 1:**

$$F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)= \sum_{i = 1}^x q^{i-1}p$$
$$= p\sum_{i=1}^xq^{i-1}$$
$$= \frac{p}{q}\sum_{i=1}^{x} q^i$$
$$= \frac{p}{q}\frac{1 - q^{x}}{1-q}$$
$$= \frac{p}{q}\frac{1 - q^{x}}{p}$$
$$= \frac{1 - q^{x}}{q}$$

**Method 2:**

Note that $P(X > x)$ is the probability of at least $x$ failures in a row.

$$F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)= 1 - P(X > x)$$
$$= 1 - q^x$$

Why is one of these incorrect?

Comment: Substitute $x=1$ to see that $\sum_{i=1}^xq^i\neq\frac{1-q^x}{1-q}$. Method 2 is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In method 1,
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^{x} q^{i-1} = \frac{1-q^x}{1-q},
$$
which is the reason why your computation is wrong. So,
\begin{align*}
  F_X(x) &= \sum_{i=1}^{x} q^{i-1} p \\
  &= p \sum_{i=1}^{x} q^{i-1} \\
  &= p \frac{1-q^x}{1-q} \\
  &= 1 - q^x.
\end{align*}